# Getting error while calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

My function following values in parameter

```
function viewStudent(schoolName, fullName, class, rollnumber) {

}
```

Here are the values stored in student object.:

```
schoolName="St Joseph's School" 
fullName="xyz" 
rollNumber=2019,
```

While calling viewStudent I pass value as:

```
onclick="changeFormStatus('${studentValue.schoolName}','${studentValue.fullName}',
 '${studentValue.rollNumber}', '${studentValue.class}')"
```

But as the schoolName contains apostrophe, It is giving error of `"missing )"`. Any Idea how I can handle this issue.

Comment: `class` is also a reserved keyword.

Comment: do you mean to call the `viewStudent` function from the onClick event? If so, you're calling the wrong function. Also the arguments are in the wrong order

Answer (score 2):

use backtick(`) instead of apostrophe(') on parameters:

```
onclick="changeFormStatus(`${studentValue.schoolName}`,`${studentValue.fullName}`,
 `${studentValue.rollNumber}`, `${studentValue.class}`)"
```

Comment: What if school name contains backtick?

Comment: @bakusC what if the school name contains double quotes?